# Jquery .live event not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a simple question regarding `.live` touch events. What I am trying to do is when the user clicks/touches the main body of the page (container), the `refreshCanvas` function is called. However this doesn't seem to work for me.

**JavaScript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function refreshCanvas () {
    var code = document.getElementById('iframe');
    code.src = code.src; // that is the essence here
  }
  setInterval(refreshIframe1, 20000);
  function refreshIframe1() {
    $("#iframe")[0].src = $("#iframe")[0].src;
  }
  $('#container').live("tap", function() {
    refreshCanvas();
  });
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
  <a href="javascript:refreshCanvas()"><img src="data/refresh.jpg"></a>
  <div id="container">  
    <iframe id="iframe" src="data/canvas.html"  z-index: 0; style="border: 0; position:absolute; top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0; width:100%; height:100%"></iframe> 
  </div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using the latest version of jQuery (1.9), [they have removed the `.live()` method of binding events entirely](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#live-removed) and reccommend you use/learn the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method.

```
$('.something').live('event', function(){...});
```

is equivalent to

```
$(document).on('event', '.something', function(){...});
```

Answer (score 1):

[`.live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) has been deprecated in jQuery since v1.7, and has been removed in v1.9.

You should replace it with [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

`.on` has 2 syntaxes for binding elements, whereas `.live` only had 1.

If the element exists at the time you are binding, you do it like this:

`$('.element').on('click', function(){
    });`

You can even use the shorthand:

`$('.element').click(function(){
    });`

If the element does not exist at the time, or new ones will be added (which is what `.live` was normally used for), you need to use "event delegation":

`$(document).on('click', '.element', function(){
    });`

NOTE: You want to bind to the closest static element, not always `document`.
In the meantime, the [**jQuery Migrate plugin**](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-migrate-plugin) can be used to restore the `.live()` functionality.